# space around div with background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, spaces

i'm trying to create a frame that will contain a dynamic amount of text.
it has rounded corners so a created 3 divs:top, body and bottom.
body will hold the content while top & bottom only display the respective images of the frame.
all this can be seen here:

http://www.m-challenge.com/nimrod/modular_frame.php

the problem:
there is a space  those top and bottom divs and the middle one.
please take a look and any input would be highly appreciated.
have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the `p` tag has some margin on top/bottom. Give it a margin of 0 to fix that. The same would apply if you put any `h#`, `ul` and similar tags in the box.

Also, can I recommend you not spend so much time making rounded courners this way and simply use CSS3's border-radius? I know, it's not fully supported yet but you have support from most browsers apart from IE, and IE users simply get a gracefull fall back to a square box. Just a suggestion

Comment: CSS3 is almost entirely unsupported on the interwebs, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Almost entirely unsupported? Please back up your claims with an actual source. Oh, http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus#target-selector :)

I never said for him to use CSS3 exclusively, but if you can gracefully fall back with some of it and it won't majorly affect your web site, it is worth using.

Comment: Thank you very much, setting p to margin: 0px; padding:0px;
did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first reset margins and paddings:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

then apply the proper values, depending on the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: thanx for the advice and the link. using reset sheets sounds like a good idea.